# PostgreSQL: How to select last balance for each account on each day in a given date range?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

I am running PostgreSQL 9.3 and have a table that looks something like this:

```
     entry_date      | account_id | balance
---------------------+------------+---------
 2016-02-01 00:00:00 |        123 |     100
 2016-02-01 06:00:00 |        123 |     200
 2016-02-01 12:00:00 |        123 |     300
 2016-02-01 18:00:00 |        123 |     250
 2016-02-01 00:00:00 |        456 |     400
 2016-02-01 06:00:00 |        456 |     300
 2016-02-01 12:00:00 |        456 |     200
 2016-02-01 18:00:00 |        456 |     299
 2016-02-02 00:00:00 |        123 |     250
 2016-02-02 06:00:00 |        123 |     300
 2016-02-02 12:00:00 |        123 |     400
 2016-02-02 18:00:00 |        123 |     450
 2016-02-02 00:00:00 |        456 |     299
 2016-02-02 06:00:00 |        456 |     200
 2016-02-02 12:00:00 |        456 |     100
 2016-02-02 18:00:00 |        456 |       0
(16 rows)
```

My goal is to retrieve the final balance for each account, each day in a given date range. So my desired result is:

```
     entry_date      | account_id | balance
---------------------+------------+---------
 2016-02-01 18:00:00 |        123 |     250
 2016-02-01 18:00:00 |        456 |     299
 2016-02-02 18:00:00 |        123 |     450
 2016-02-02 18:00:00 |        456 |       0
(4 rows)
```

Note that the timestamps in my example are much neater than in reality...I can't always rely on 18:00 as the last time of each day.

How would I write this SQL query?

I tried variations of this:

```
SELECT max(entry_date), account_id, max(balance)
FROM ledger
WHERE entry_date BETWEEN '2016-02-01'::timestamp AND '2016-02-02'::timestamp
GROUP BY account_id, entry_date;
```

Here is the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE ledger (
  entry_date    timestamp(3),
  account_id    int,
  balance       int
);

INSERT INTO ledger VALUES ('2016-02-01T00:00:00.000Z', 123, 100);
INSERT INTO ledger VALUES ('2016-02-01T06:00:00.000Z', 123, 200);
INSERT INTO ledger VALUES ('2016-02-01T12:00:00.000Z', 123, 300);
INSERT INTO ledger VALUES ('2016-02-01T18:00:00.000Z', 123, 250);

INSERT INTO ledger VALUES ('2016-02-01T00:00:00.000Z', 456, 400);
INSERT INTO ledger VALUES ('2016-02-01T06:00:00.000Z', 456, 300);
INSERT INTO ledger VALUES ('2016-02-01T12:00:00.000Z', 456, 200);
INSERT INTO ledger VALUES ('2016-02-01T18:00:00.000Z', 456, 299);

INSERT INTO ledger VALUES ('2016-02-02T00:00:00.000Z', 123, 250);
INSERT INTO ledger VALUES ('2016-02-02T06:00:00.000Z', 123, 300);
INSERT INTO ledger VALUES ('2016-02-02T12:00:00.000Z', 123, 400);
INSERT INTO ledger VALUES ('2016-02-02T18:00:00.000Z', 123, 450);

INSERT INTO ledger VALUES ('2016-02-02T00:00:00.000Z', 456, 299);
INSERT INTO ledger VALUES ('2016-02-02T06:00:00.000Z', 456, 200);
INSERT INTO ledger VALUES ('2016-02-02T12:00:00.000Z', 456, 100);
INSERT INTO ledger VALUES ('2016-02-02T18:00:00.000Z', 456, 0);
```

Here is a SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/56886

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` with `PARTITION BY`:

```
SELECT entry_date, account_id, balance
FROM (
  SELECT entry_date, account_id, balance, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY account_id, entry_date::date 
                            ORDER BY entry_date DESC) AS rn
  FROM ledger
  WHERE entry_date BETWEEN '2016-02-01'::timestamp AND '2016-02-02'::timestamp) AS t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

`PARTITION BY` creates slices of `account_id` values per day since `entry_date` is also used in the same clause *after being cast to a date value*. Each slice is ordered by `entry_date` in descending order, hence `ROW_NUMBER = 1` corresponds to the last record of the day.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/56886/3)

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres, I think the easiest method is `distinct on`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (account_id) l.*
FROM ledger l
WHERE entry_date BETWEEN '2016-02-01'::timestamp AND '2016-02-02'::timestamp
ORDER BY account_id, entry_date DESC;
```

`DISTINCT ON` sorts the data based on the keys in the `ORDER BY`.  It then chooses unique values of the keys in the `ON` list, choosing the first value encountered.

EDIT:

*Exactly* the same idea applies for one record for day -- I simply misread the original requirement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (account_id, date_trunc('day', entry_date)) l.*
FROM ledger l
WHERE entry_date BETWEEN '2016-02-01'::timestamp AND '2016-02-02'::timestamp
ORDER BY account_id, date_trunc('day', entry_date), entry_date DESC;
```

Comment: I dig how concise this is, but unfortunately it only returns rows for the last day in the date range. I need a row for each account on each day in the date range (expecting four rows, got two).